# Why is Remote Desktop Services missing from Group Policy Management in Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, rdp, group-policy

I have SBS 2008 and my client PC's are not able to RDP to each other. The settings are grayed out due to being joined to the domain.

No prob, right?  go into **Group Policy Management**, and locate this section to make changes:

> Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows
>   Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host

Except, shoot!. Windows Components\ **Remote Desktop Services** is not even in the list!  Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you ever find out? None of the answers seem to work in 2015. There just is not Terminal Services template.

Answer (score 1):

You can get to it using *Start > Search* "gpedit.msc", then go to

```
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > 
Windows Components > Terminal Services > Terminal Server > Connections.
```

Answer (score 0):

It called different things in different systems.
It may be called as Terminal Services.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on "Administrative Templates", select "Add/Remove Templates ..." and verify that the "system" template is there

Answer (score 0):

Right-click Administrative Templates, select Add/Remove.

Remove an item (I removed inetres) and close.

The templates rearranges and expands. At this point Terminal Services should now be listed.

Right-click Administrative Templates and add back the item you removed.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue, and the solution in articles I found was to use an older machine from which to edit the GPO.  You'd have to try from a Windows XP or Windows 2003 machine.

However, I didn't have any of those available on the network anymore.

In the end, I deleted the following folder under the policy I was working with, and those settings no longer appear.  (There is an ini file in that folder that defines the 3 settings we want to remove.)

```
\\domain\sysvol\domain\Policies\GUIDOfPolicy\User\Microsoft\RemoteInstall
```

To find the GUIDOfPolicy, look in GPMC under Details.  You will see it as the Unique ID.

Remember to substitute your domain name as you look for this folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clean this up on a policy of mine.

Reference this article for instructions: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2722241/policy-reporting-tools-indicate-empty-internet-explorer-maintenance-policy-as-winning

And then remove these instead of the ones listed there:
[{3060E8D0-7020-11D2-842D-00C04FA372D4}{3060E8CE-7020-11D2-842D-00C04FA372D4}]

Comment: Please include the content of the external resource within your answer.

Answer (score -1):

If

*Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Terminal Services > Terminal Server*

does not appear in

*gpedit.msc*

then go into

*%windir%\system32\GroupPolicy*

and rename the

*Adm*

folder to

*Adm-renamed*.

Run *gpedit.msc* and the *Adm* folder should be recreated correctly and the *Terminal Server* policies should be visible. You can then delete the *Adm-renamed* folder.